# How to iterate through fields in a Firestore Document in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Document and I would like to iterate through them. I'm trying the following code, after looking in this question [How to iterate through all fields in a firebase document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595082/how-to-iterate-through-all-fields-in-a-firebase-document)

```dart
FutureBuilder(
                                  future:   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc('doc').get();,
                                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      

                                      
                                      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                      



                                      for (var entry in data.keys) {
                                        // actions
                                      }

                                      

                                  }

                              ),
```

This code results in `type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`

Comment: After many hours I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
                  future:   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc('doc').get();,
                                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
                     if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;


                                      for (var match in data.keys) {
                                       // actions
                                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

[data](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) is a method, not a property on [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).  Call it using parenthesis:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: yes I think yes